# Cannot set Break Point in Intellij-IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I am running a Maven project and while trying to debug the application, in some lines I'm getting an error `No Executable line found at <line no>` error even though the code gets executed. I have tried `File->Invalidate Cache / Restart` method. Appreciate any solutions.
IntelliJ IDEA version: 2018.2.4
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried cleaning and rebuilding project ?

Comment: usually, it means that there are differences between your source code and the execute one. Just make sure you don't have something like proguard (that might move lines) and you deploy/run the correct version of your application (that was built using the latest version of the source code).

Comment: @RomanProshin I think that is the problem and Cleaning and rebuilding works. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking what configuration you are running, I was having similar problem when I didn`t set the configuration right.

You can also use the Run with coverage to see where the code is going :)

Hope this was helpful.